# Logic difficulty in for-loop & if-else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, logic

I am having some logic problem when doing packaging system. Let me explain the situation first, there is **listCapacity** for each category. There is also a **SPUItemList** to store the standard packing unit items.

First, I need to check whether the stock for items in SPUItemList is enough or not. If they are not enough, I get from the **prodSubstitute**. prodSubstitute is a list of items sorted descending by stockLevel and by each category. Once I added into **prodIDList**, I minus the listCapacity.

If they are enough stockLevel, I straight away add into prodIDList and minus the listCapacity.

Here is the codes:

```
        List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> SPUItemList = new     List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
        List<string> prodIDList = new List<string>();
        List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItem = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
        //Get total amount of packages needed by each distribution
        packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

        //Get the items in standard packing unit
        SPUItemList = packBLL.getAllSPUItemByDistributionID(distributionID);
        for (int i = 0; i < SPUItemList.Count; i++)
        {
            //Get the product quantity of each item in standard packing unit
            productQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(SPUItemList[i].productQuantity);

            //Get the total stock unit of each product in standard packing unit
            totalProductUnit = prodPackBLL.getTotalProductUnit(SPUItemList[i].id);

            if ((productQuantity * packagesNeeded) > totalProductUnit)
            {
                //Get the category name of the item which has not enough stock
                category = SPUItemList[i].categoryName;

                //Get the list of substitute product with top 5 highest storage level
                List<ProductPacking> prodSubstitute = new List<ProductPacking>();

                //Find list of substitute with highest stock level and replace the product
                prodSubstitute = prodPackBLL.getProductIDWithHighestStock(category);

                for (int count = 0; count < prodSubstitute.Count; count++)
                {
                    //To prevent duplication of same product and check for the listCapacity
                    if (prodSubstitute[count].id != SPUItemList[i].id && !prodIDList.Contains(prodSubstitute[count].id) && count < listCapacity)
                    {
                        prodIDList.Add(prodSubstitute[count].id);
                        listCapacity--;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //If the stock is enough, add it into the prodIDList straight away
                prodIDList.Add(SPUItemList[i].id);
                listCapacity--;
            }
```

So my question is, if they are enough stockLevel and I added into prodIDList, how can I fix my code so that they know the listCapacity for this category has been deducted? Because so far I have some logic problem with this portion of codes.

Sorry for my poor explanation and I hope you all understand what am I talking about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is listCapacity a property of Category?

Comment: No, it's just a string variable for me to check the for-loop

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this (replaced the listCapacity with categoryCheck and checked it):

```
List<string> lstCategory = new List<string>();
List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> SPUItemList = new     List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
List<string> prodIDList = new List<string>();
List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItem = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
//Get total amount of packages needed by each distribution
packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

    //Get the items in standard packing unit
SPUItemList = packBLL.getAllSPUItemByDistributionID(distributionID);

for (int i = 0; i < SPUItemList.Count; i++)
{
    //Get the product quantity of each item in standard packing unit
    productQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(SPUItemList[i].productQuantity);

    //Get the total stock unit of each product in standard packing unit
    totalProductUnit = prodPackBLL.getTotalProductUnit(SPUItemList[i].id);

    if ((productQuantity * packagesNeeded) > totalProductUnit)
    {
        //Get the category name of the item which has not enough stock
        category = SPUItemList[i].categoryName;

        //Get the list of substitute product with top 5 highest storage level
        List<ProductPacking> prodSubstitute = new List<ProductPacking>();

        //Find list of substitute with highest stock level and replace the product
        prodSubstitute = prodPackBLL.getProductIDWithHighestStock(category);

        for (int count = 0; count < prodSubstitute.Count; count++)
        {
            //To prevent duplication of same product and check for the listCapacity
            if (prodSubstitute[count].id != SPUItemList[i].id && !prodIDList.Contains(prodSubstitute[count].id) &&  !(lstCategory.Where(x=>x.Equals(category)).Select(x=>x).Count() > 2))
            {
                prodIDList.Add(prodSubstitute[count].id);
                //listCapacity--;
                lstCategory.Add(category);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //If the stock is enough, add it into the prodIDList straight away
        category = SPUItemList[i].categoryName;
        if(!prodIDList.Contains(SPUItemList[i].id) &&   !(lstCategory.Where(x=>x.Equals(category)).Select(x=>x).Count() > 2))
        {
            prodIDList.Add(SPUItemList[i].id);
            //listCapacity--;
            lstCategory.Add(category);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to limit the listCapacity for each category to 2. So each category may have 2 products

Comment: @Gwen  - can each category have same product twice?

Comment: Nope, cannot have duplicate and there is a check for duplicate inside the if statement. Unfortunately nope, there is still one product for each category. I am trying to set 2 products for each category

Comment: Okay, now limited to 2 products for each category.

Comment: @afzaluluh Let's say I got product 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. My product 1 has enough storage so it's added into the prodIDList first. Then I loop thru. Product 2 is not enough so it skips. And product 3, 4 and 5 all enough storage. It supposed to return me product 1 and 3 only. Instead, it returns me 3, and 4.

Comment: Sure sure, take your time. Thanks for the effort :) really really thank you!

Comment: Also it just happens to one of my category only. Other works fine. The situation is product 1 2units, 2 50units, 3 40 units, 4 55units. Product 1 and 3 in SPUItemList. So it supposed to return me product 3 and 4 instead of 2 and 4

Comment: I think there's a problem in my logic. this part `!(lstCategory.Where(x => x.Equals(category)).Select(x => x).Count() > 2)` should be `!(lstCategory.Where(x => x.Equals(category)).Select(x => x).Count() > 1)` in both part. Can you try this?

Comment: Yaya I set it to >= 2. But it still returns me 3 and 4 instead of 2 and 4 as in the post above.

Comment: I think now the issue is with order. Probably we need to loop in opposite way!

Comment: Loop in opposite way as in?

Comment: Yeah! It works. Would you mind to explain the loop in opposite way and LINQ query part?

Comment: I am not sure about the reverse loop, we need to work more here. Linq part is simple, from the List lstCategory we are selecting those catories which are in our current category and we are counting them and taking them if there are less than 2 occurrences.

Comment: How do we know, in the given scenario, it is supposed to return 3, not 2?

Comment: Because from my codes, first it will check if the item is in SPUItemList. They only will be replaced when there is insufficient storage. Since product 1 and 3 is in the SPUItemList in the first place, and product 3 is sufficient, it should be added into prodIDList. At the same time, product 1 which is insufficient, it should be replace by the product in prodSubstitute.

Comment: So, product 2 is not sufficient?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44260/discussion-between-gwen-and-afzalulh)